# Fedora 26: Chromium does not start

Tags: fedora, vmware, chrome

I have a fresh installation of Fedora 26 in VMWare Player (`uname -a: Linux localhost.localdomain 4.12.8-300.fc26.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 17 15:30:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`) and my first action after set up was to install Chromium. But starting Chromium did not work. I reinstalled Fedora 26 from netinstall again and installed Chromium again. But I couldn't start Chromium again.

The installation itself worked without any errors.

I can see that Chromium is in the top bar of Gnome where the active application is shown but the window of Chromium does not appear. After a few seconds I clicked on the entry in the top, Fedora 26 asks me to kill the application because it's not responding.

I installed Fedora using the official fedora repositories. As requested:

```
[tjati@localhost ~]$ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 60.0.3112.101 Fedora Project
```

How can I use Chromium?

Comment: If the installation failed, how do you expect to use `Chromium`? Please edit your question with the error's shown during installation.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I edited my post and made clear that the installation itself worked but not starting Chromium itself.

Comment: Are you installing Chromium from the fedora repo? Can you run the command `chromium --version` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Yes and I added the output you asked for.

Comment: What does it say whey you just run `chromium-browser` in the terminal? Maybe it's saying something. Maybe even in dmesg/syslog.

Comment: There's no output running chromium-browser in the terminal. I couldn't find anything in dmesg or in /var/log.

Comment: add uname -a output please.

Comment: I added the output of `uname -a `)

Comment: Bump (I've the same issue but not investigated yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll have to disable 3D acceleration within the VMware host settings. That was the only way I was able to get it to launch properly.

Comment: A reinstall of fedora was required, but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Xen2050's instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388661/fedora-26-chromium-does-not-start#comment692205_388661), I tried this - and it gave the answer for me. You can’t run Chromium as root with no sandbox.

Logged out as root and back in as a user, worked OK.